# Sub report Drill down

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I Created a crystal report with raw data in main report. and I have 5 sub reports associated with that which I cannot link it to main report. Now each of the sub report has summarizations (hard coded) of the main report. Now how can I get the drill down of the raw data when I click the summarization in sub report?

Comment: Couldnt understand your requirement

Comment: So i have 5 sub reports which are hard coded to give the summarisations of the raw data. Raw data is in another crystal report. So I added these 5 sub reports to the crystal report containing raw data. But i cannot link the sub reports with raw data. Can I get the drill downs from the summarizations